# Why thread_id creates not in order?

Tags: multithreading, unix

I tried to create 10 threads, and output each tread index. My code is shown as below, I am wondering why   they are repeating instead of arranging in order?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "util.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
pthread_mutex_t request_buf_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void * worker(void *arg)
{
    int thread_id = *(int*)arg;
    //  int requests_handled = 0;
    //requests_handled = requests_handled + 1;
printf("%d\n",thread_id);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{


    pthread_t dispatchers[100];
    pthread_t workers[100];


    int i;
    int * thread_id = malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            *thread_id = i;
            pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, worker, (void*)thread_id);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output result is:
4
5
5
6
6
6
7
8
9
9

But I expected it as:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Anyone has any idea or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 10 threads execute in parallel, and they all share a single `int` object, the one created by the call to `malloc`.

By the time your first thread executes its `printf` call, the value of `*thread_id` has been set to `4`. Your second and third threads execute their `printf` calls when `*thread_id` has been set to `5`. And so on.

If you allocate a separate `int` object for each thread (either by moving the `malloc` call inside the loop or just by declaring an array of `int`s), you'll get a unique thread id in each thread. But they're still likely to be printed in arbitrary order, since there's no synchronization among the threads.